# Examining given sets on convexity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Two sets are given $\{x \in [0,∞)^2\ |\ f(x,y) > 1\}$, and $\{x \in [0,∞)^2\ |\ f(x,y) \leq 1\}$ respectively. I should now examine these sets for convexity in the function 
$f(x,y)= x^2y$. My first idea was to form the Hessian matrix of the function to see whether it is positive (semi-)definite. If I am not mistaken, the leading diagonal yields $2y$ and $0$. But I have no idea how to demonstrate that the *sets* are convex.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you mean to say $(x,y)\in[0,\infty)^2$?

Comment: Yes, I did mean to say this.

Answer (score 1):

The second set is not convex: take the points $A=(1,1)$ and $B=(2,1/4)$, check that they belong to the set and that $(A+B)/2$ does not.

The first set is the strict epigraph of the convex function $g:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=1/x^2$, and thus convex.

Comment: I understand, why the first set is convex. But is there a general approach to determining convexity apart from picking a pair of two elements from the set?

Comment: I would not say that there is a "standard" procedure to use. Ways to check the convexity are: the definition of convex set, convex function $\Longrightarrow$ its sublevel sets are convex and the (strict) epigraph of a function $f$ is a convex set iff $f$ is convex. 

Note that I did not prove convexity for the second set, I found two points that violate the definition of convex set (i.e. a counterexample). I made this guess via drawing.